# Tkinter - как привязать к клавише 1,2,3 событие?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу программу на Tkinter, понадобилось привязать событие к клавише 1, а также к Ctrl
Как это можно сделать, используя `widget.bind()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105688/binding-multiple-events-on-same-widget-to-the-same-callback-function

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант решения. Таблица с кнопками https://docs.huihoo.com/tkinter/tkinter-reference-a-gui-for-python/key-names.html

```
from tkinter import *


#После нажатия
def b1(event):
    txt = Label(window, text="Вот так)", font=("Lucida Grande", 15))
    txt.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='c')


window = Tk()
window.title("TEST")
window.minsize(1200, 600)

#Реакция на нажатие левый ctrl
window.bind("<Control_L>", b1)

window.mainloop()
```